# Populate my Select Dropdown based on date picked from Datepicker

Tags: jquery, view, datepicker, controller

I have a datepicker which allows you to pick the date. Once this date is picked, I need my select dropdown to be populated with dynamic time data. Pretty much, I am building an online ordering service. once you select the date, it will give you time intervals within that date selected of when you can come and pick up your order from store. those timeframes are based on the store's business hours. How can I achieve this? This is what I have so far.

This is my view:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    @{
        var store = (Site)ViewData["sites"];
        var concept = (Concept)Session["concept"];

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div>
                <h3>@store.name</h3>
                <p>
                    @store.address1<br />
                    @store.city, @store.state @store.zip<br />
                    @store.phone
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Pick Up Time</h4>
                When do you want to pick up your order?
                <br /> Soon As Possible @Html.RadioButton("pickUp", @store.getOrderingASAPTime(), new { @checked = "checked" })
                (Pick up will be ready at: @store.getOrderingASAPTime().ToShortTimeString())
                <br />Select Another time @Html.RadioButton("pickUp", "differentTime")
            </div>
            <div class="calender">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="Pick a Date">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1" id="timepick">
                    <select class="form-control " id="timepicker">
                    </select>
                </div>
                @section scripts {
                    <script>
                        $(function () {




                            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "DD mm-dd-yy",
                                minDate: 0,
                                autoclose: true,
                                onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {

                                    updateAb(selected);
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        function updateAb(value) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeOptions", "OrderTime")',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: { a: "testing" },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function () { alert('Success'); },
                                error: function () { alert('Error'); }
                            });
                        };
                    </script>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6"><br />
            <h4>Store Hours</h4>
            Monday @store.MonOpen - @store.MonClose
            <br />Tuesday @store.TueOpen - @store.TueClose
            <br />Wednesday @store.WedOpen - @store.WedClose
            <br />Thursday @store.ThuOpen - @store.ThuClose
            <br />Friday @store.FriOpen - @store.FriClose
            <br />Saturday @store.SatOpen - @store.SatClose
            <br />Sunday @store.SunOpen - @store.SunClose
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-4" style="padding-top: 20px;">        
        <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick='window.location = "@Url.Action("MenuPage", "MenuPage", new { siteID = @store.seq })";'
                style="background-color: @concept.PrimaryBackgroundColor; color: @concept.PrimaryForegroundColor;">Place Order</button>
                        <div><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "StoreListing")">Not The Store You Want?</a></div>
        </div>            
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#datepicker').hide();
                            $('#timepicker').hide();
                            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
                                if ($(this).attr('value') == 'differentTime') {
                                    $('#datepicker').show();
                                    $('#timepicker').show();
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    $('#datepicker').hide();
                                    $('#timepicker').hide();
                                }
                        });
                        });
                    </script>
    }
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class OrderTimeController : Controller
{
    // GET: OrderTime
    public ActionResult StoreInfo(int siteID)
    {

        Site result = SiteMgmt.GetSite(siteID);
        var emptyResult = new Site();
        if (siteID == 0)
        {
            View().ViewData["sites"] = emptyResult;
        }
        else
        {
            View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetTimeOptions(DateTime pickUpDate)
    {

        Site site = View().ViewData["sites"] as Site;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        switch (pickUpDate.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                startTime = site.OOSunStart;
                endTime = site.OOSunEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                startTime = site.OOMonStart;
                endTime = site.OOMonEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                startTime = site.OOTueStart;
                endTime = site.OOTueEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                startTime = site.OOWedStart;
                endTime = site.OOWedEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                startTime = site.OOThuStart;
                endTime = site.OOThuEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                startTime = site.OOFriStart;
                endTime = site.OOFriEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                startTime = site.OOSatStart;
                endTime = site.OOSatEnd;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        if (pickUpDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            if (startTime.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
            {
                startTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(site.leadTime);
            }
        }

        DateTime tempTime = startTime;

        do
        {
            tempTime = tempTime.AddMinutes(15);
            results.Add(tempTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        } while (tempTime <= endTime);


        View().ViewData["availableTimes"] = results;


        return View();
    }
}
}
```

So as you can see there is an action in my controller that will go through and pick the times for whatever day of the week is selected. How can I call this action into my view? and then, how can I populate my select drop down with the times for that day? Any help is appreciated! :)

**UPDATE!!!**
I updated my view with an ajax call but it keeps returning an error. Does that mean it is not hitting this method in the controller?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation (for the 3rd time!)

Comment: Not a lot of this code is making any sense. You script includes a `GetTimeOptions($("#datepicker").val());` but you have not shown your `GetTimeOptions()` function. You do however have a `GetTimeOptions()` controller method. If you want to call that, then you need ajax to call the method and in its success callback, update the DOM. But why not just include those in the DOM in the first place?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey I updated my view a little. I took out the GetTimeOptions() function. I made an ajax call but it keeps returning an error alert. Does this mean it is not hitting my controller method and running through the code to pick which day of the week has been picked from datepicker? This is very complicated for me I'm sorry.

Comment: There are multiple errors with your ajax function. Your passing `data: { a: "testing" },` but that method does not contain a parameter named `a`. Your parameter is `DateTime pickUpDate` so `"testing"` would not even bind to a `DateTime`. Your setting `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` but your not using `JSON.stringify()` (just delete the `contentType` since its unnecessary). You specify `dataType: "json",` but your method returns html. And then most of the code in your methodmakes no sense anyway - for example `Site site = View().ViewData["sites"] as Site;` will just be `null`